# Enterprise iPad: Limit which wifi network can connect to

Tags: wifi, security, settings, enterprise

I'm looking for a policy setting or a creative solution here. Is there a way to restrict the wifi networks an iOS device can connect to? We have business issued iPads, but are worried that they can be taken off-site and access company data elsewhere. If we could restrict that only the company wifi can be used, and no other public or home networks, we could mitigate this security concern. Ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't be the right solution to simply restrict external access of your data?

Comment: This a million times ^

Comment: Yes, the ultimate security solution would actually be to not use computers. Then we wouldn't have to worry about hackers or security policies. But that doesn't help people who are using technology. IPads are a great step forward in allowing for data mobility, accuracy of information and communication. In our business we have a production floor that's not very tech savvy, and we're trying to change that. Why is it wrong to try and find a way to use technology in a secure way?

Comment: @SebastianSemmler I don't mean to imply that we are giving external access to the devices. The iPads are meant to be used in an area of the company with no computers but WiFi. To make company data accessible from the devices, the current solution is to use a third-party app to give access to our network drives/folders on the device. Unfortunately, those apps still use the cloud as a go-between, because there's no raw access between an iPad and a Windows network share. If there were, I'd love to know about it (provided it could enforce permissions and other security policies).

Comment: I see a major problem. You trust a third party external access to your server, but not your employees. If you want give your users access to your shares on there iOS devices, did you looked into WebDAV?

Comment: Not necessarily. If you vet the right service, you can get full end-to-end encryption with your own secret private key. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Just found something called Work Folders on Windows Server 2012. It claims to be compatible with iOS, and is built straight into the server OS. I'll have to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with [Apples MGM tools](https://www.apple.com/support/business/apple-configurator/).